# C# - user32.dll - GetWindowRect problem

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
    public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
    public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
    public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
}

foreach (Process pr in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    RECT rc;
    GetWindowRect(???, out rc);
```

What should I put for " ??? " ? . It tells me I have to put a HandleRef object but I do not know how to get HandleRef object from Process method.

Comment: You've skipped a step; you need to get the native handle from the window first.  For example, if the window were the C# main form in your application (assuming a WinForms app) you would use new `HandleRef( this, this.Handle );`  You need to first get a handle to the window in question (and Process.Handle is likely not it).

Answer (score 10):

If you need window coordinates for a window already in your process, there are other ways to get a window handle that don't require enumerating processes.

For WinForms windows, use the `Handle` property.

[System.Windows.Forms.Control ... Handle Property @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx)

For WPF applications, use `WindowInteropHelper`

[System.Windows.Interop ... WindowInteropHelper Class @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.windowinterophelper.handle.aspx)

If you are trying to enumerate windows that you aren't able to access directly from .NET; say from a 3rd party control that creates a top-level window out of scope of your code, you may wish to enumerate via the win32 `EnumWindows` function.

[EnumWindows (Win32) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Signatures for P/Invoke for EnumWindows are available here:

[User32.dll EnumWindows @ pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumWindows)

**Added:**

Looks like you want to enumerate all the windows & associated processes. Use `EnumWindows`, then call `GetWindowThreadProcessId` to get the associated Process & Unmanaged Thread ID for each window.

[GetWindowThreadProcessId (Win32) @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The P/Invoke signature is available here:

[User32.dll GetWindowThreadProcessId @ pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowThreadProcessId.html)

Last, you can get a Process object via the static method `GetProcessById`.

[Process.GetProcessById @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

**Added (#2):**

Here's a short console program that can enumerate windows, process & thread ids. There are a few differences from your snippet.

1. I use IntPtr, not HandleRef. As other people have pointed out, this may be confusing things for you.
2. I didn't specify a `return` attribute. If this is required, you should be able to add it back in.
3. I'm running as administrator; some things may run differently for you if you are running with user-level privileges.

[C# Source Code Example @ gist.github](https://gist.github.com/841560)

Comment: thank you! but I'm confused. Yeah, It looks like it does not let me to access to another processes' window properties from .NET

Comment: I was able to get a sample working; but I'm running as administrator on my machine. I'll post a link to the source code so that you may try it out in a test project in your environment.

Answer (score 4):

This will work, but at first you need to find an IntPtr hwnd of the window using winapi functions like [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rect rectangle);

Rect r = new Rect();
GetWindowRect(hwnd, ref r);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using new HandleRef(pr, pr.MainWindowHandle) might work.  Assuming that your program actually has a main window.  There are definitely easier ways to get this info.

Your foreach loop is going to need work, that doesn't compile on Process.GetCurrentProcess().  Trying to iterate all the processes is going to bomb the code, you'll get privileged system processes that don't care much about sharing information.  It is impossible to guess why you are trying to do this.  Use EnumWindows to enumerate all toplevel windows on the desktop.

Comment: HandleRef(pr, pr.MainWindowHandle) does not work.

Thank you for Process.GetCurrentProcess(). I fix'd it.

Comment: Well, change the GetWindowRect() argument to IntPtr, HandleRef is quite unnecessary anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need not a process handle but a handle of your window.

You can use some example on pinvoke http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowRect.html

Comment: I have to know all processes' handles not only the my application.

Comment: @Sergey: if you read that documentation you will realize that it doesn't apply here.  That is a process handle, not a window handle.

Comment: Your link does not help the OP (who obviously already found it).  It only shows how to get the window handle for a form within the application.  If that was the use case you wouldn't need to use GetWindowRect at all; the .NET form can already give you that info.  -1