# Process Information in WPF/C# are wrong. Same solution is working in Win Forms/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, process, window, size

Okay so I want to attach process with c#. I used "System.Diagnostic" class. So what I'm actually doing:

```
//DEFINITIONS
Process[] nameOfProcess;
IntPtr ptrToProcessWindow;
Process getProcess;
//DEFINITIONS

//INVOKE
`[DllImport("user32.dll")]`

 `public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rect rectangle);`
 //INVOKE

//USING CODE

getProcess = nameOfProcess[0];
ptrToProcessWindow = getProcess.MainWindowHandle;
GetWindowRect(ptrToProcessWindow, ref windowRect);
//USING CODE
```

So windowRect is:

```
Rect windowRect = new Rect();
```

windowRect have information about app, like:

[image]

But, result of debugging is this:

[image]

Obviously I get the wrong values from process. I already checked if the process is found, I also checked if "ptrToWindow" is correct (and it is).

I just pass `ptrToProcessWindow` and `windowRect` to function `GetWindowRect(,)` <--- LOOK AT //USING CODE//

P.S. I'm using exactly the same method in C# Win Forms and it works perfectly.

Comment: Oh also, if anyone wonder what is nameOfProcess[] --> 
Process[] nameOfProcess

nameOfProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);

Comment: Did you already look at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098994/c-sharp-user32-dll-getwindowrect-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debugger screenshot shows floating point values.  That cannot be correct, the native Windows [RECT structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) only use integer members.  So an obvious guess at the problem is that you used the WPF Rect type in your pinvoke declaration.  It is a *drastic* mismatch with RECT, garbage is expected.

You'll have to declare your own:

```
private struct RECT {
    public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
}
```

And fix your [DllImport] declaration to use RECT instead.

Fwiw, the System.Drawing.Rectangle struct is not a match either, it uses Width and Height instead of Right and Bottom.  It looks better in the debugger, less garbage.

Comment: This is correct. Fixed. I would vote up but I just joined. What do you mean by "to use RECT instead"?

Comment: You have to fix your declaration for GetWindowRect.  Change "Rect" to "RECT".

Comment: Oh I see. I figured it out yes. Thank you anyway, Sir :).